# How to ignore case sensitive in Suggester? Solr 3.6

Tags: solr

Currently working on Suggester in Solr 3.6. I've configure Suggester with providing external dictionary source.

solrconfig.xml:

```
 <searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">

    <str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">textSpell</str>

  <lst name="spellchecker">
      <str name="name">suggest</str>
      <str name="classname">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.Suggester</str>
      <str name="lookupImpl">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.tst.TSTLookup</str>
      <float name="threshold">0.005</float>
      <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
    <bool name="exactMatchFirst">true</bool>
     <str name="sourceLocation">D:\source.txt</str>

    </lst>

  </searchComponent>
```

Source.txt:

```
nokia   2
nokia 5233  3
nokia 5130  2
Symbian 1
samsung 6712    2
htc 2
HTC Wild    6
htc one 7
Nokia 1280  5
```

When I'm trying to search with "n", it suggests me below result

```
nokia 5233
nokia 5130
nokia
```

but result is not included with "Nokia 1280".

What could be the reason?
How to ignore case sensitive in Suggester?

Comment: Which field you using for suggestion? Please show its type and schema.xml part of it

Comment: He isn't using a field at all.  He is using an external dictionary file.

Answer (score 1):

I think this article will help you, https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Suggester

Try to use "field" parameter in your suggester

```
    <searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">
       <str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">textSpell</str>
       <lst name="spellchecker">
          <str name="name">suggest</str>
          <str name="classname">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.Suggester</str>
          <str name="lookupImpl">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.tst.TSTLookup</str>
          <float name="threshold">0.005</float>
          <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
          <bool name="exactMatchFirst">true</bool>
          <str name="field">phoneName</str>
          <str name="sourceLocation">D:\source.txt</str>
       </lst>
    </searchComponent>
```

Field type definition

```
    <fieldType class="solr.TextField" name="textSuggest" positionIncrementGap="100">
       <analyzer>
          <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
          <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
          <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
       </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

Field definetion

```
    <field name="phoneName" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" required="false" multiValued="false"/>
```